# How to find a remainder of $\frac{3^{208}}{2}$ without an calculator?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics

$$\frac{3^{208}}{2^{109}}\text{?}$$ I wasn't able to get the exact question source but I believe there's been a typo. Should be something like$3^{208}$ mod 2 which has been clarified in many other questions. Deeply sorry for the confusion! Thank you all!!

Comment: Is there something specific you mean by "remainder"? Since $\frac{3^{208}}{2^{109}}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ I do not know what is meant by remainder.

Comment: @Cornman Presumably the asker wishes to calculate $3^{208} \bmod 2^{109}$.

Comment: I was thinking of $$11^{m+n}\pmod{10^m}$$

Comment: The remainder can be as large as $2^{109} - 1$, so no you can't do this by hand (reasonably).

Comment: The remainder is a 33 digit number $275886531195588709026997180223041$. I don't think there are that many people on earth who can compute this w/o a calculator.

Comment: I was asking the mod. I got this question from a GRE Test, so I was wondering if there were some tricks in it so I could conclude the mod easily? Thanks! And sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @CatharineW Can you post the exact text of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see any simple way of doing this. For one, the modulus you have is absolutely huge : you cannot do elementary calculations with $2^{109}$.

Same exponentials  may help you estimate the quotient : in no way does it help you find the remainder.

One simplification you probably may have considered, is that $(2+1)^{208} = \sum_{i=0}^{208} \binom {208}i 2^i$. Since after $i=109$, every term is a multiple of $2^{109}$, you can eliminate these. However, that still leaves the terms $i=0$  to $108$, which is quite a task!(You could argue, a harder task than the previous one).

> $\color{red}{275886531195588709026997180223041}$

With a calculator, of course.

EDIT : If this is from a GRE test, then that is somewhat surprising. I request you to post this exact text for us, so that then I can appropriately edit this answer.

EDIT : If the question really was $3^{208} \mod 2$, then well, $3^{208}$ is odd, obviously, so there.

Comment: @CatharineW If you even observe the rest of the questions on this site you will note that they all have much smaller moduli than $2^{109}$, infact mostly single and two digit numbers, since these allow elementary simplification and detection of patterns. This must be a printing mistake, if it is from the GRE.

Comment: I believe you are right. I haven't yet studied for the test and was trying to help a friend. I looked through all the practice exams and couldn't find something like this as well. I'll check with her! Thanks!

Comment: @CatharineW You are welcome! If you like, you can keep this question open so that when you do get confirmation of a different question, you can re-edit this question. Until then, +1.